# Since Django 1.10, my user/session data is lost with FBVs

Tags: django, django-views

I've been using views like the below since around Django 1.5, which worked like a charm in all Django versions since (including 1.9).

```
def site_info(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['site_version'] = settings.SITE_VERSION
    return render_to_response('site_info.html', context_dict, context)
```

However since Django 1.10, the page loads but no session/user data is available. It appears like the user is not logged in. When going back to a CBV, things work fine.
`Session data corrupted` is displayed when running Django.

Also, non-ASCII characters like `ë` now show as `Ã«`.

I found the problem is with `render_to_response`. When changing to `render` instead, like the below, the issues are gone.

```
def site_info(request):
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict['site_version'] = settings.SITE_VERSION
    return render(request, 'site_info.html', context_dict)
```

I read the [Django 1.10 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/) but nothing I can really point my finger to. Am I overlooking something? Why the sudden behavioral change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/):

```
The dictionary and context_instance parameters for the following functions are removed:
- django.shortcuts.render()
- django.shortcuts.render_to_response()
- django.template.loader.render_to_string()
```

Changing to `render()` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from `1.5` to `1.10` directly is a bad idea. Try `1.5` -> `1.6` -> `1.7` -> `1.8` -> `1.9` -> `1.10`.

From [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) documentation

> It’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future.

Comment: Of course I did not update from Django 1.5 straight to 1.10. Running Django 1.5 in 2016 would be a very bad idea. The functionality broke when going from 1.9 to 1.10 but the implementation was done in ~1.5; I'll clarify in my post.